# How to create word embedding using Word2Vec on Python?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, text-classification, word-embedding

I have seen many tutorials online on how to use Word2Vec (gensim).

Most tutorials are showing on how to find the `.most_similar` word or similarity between two words.

But, how if I have text data `X` and I want to produce the word embedding vector `X_vector`?

So that, this `X_vector` can be used for classification algorithms?

Comment: What difficulty did you encounter when following the tutorial from the official documentation on [how to train a model from your own data](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html#training-your-own-model) (or any other of the tutorials that explain how to do it)?

Comment: @fsimonjetz I could train the model. So, what's next? How could I produce the feature vector from the text to tain a classifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `X` is a word (string token), you can look up its vector with `word_model[X]`.

If `X` is a text - say, a list-of-words – well, a `Word2Vec` model only has vectors for words, not texts.

If you have some desired way to use a list-of-words plus per-word-vectors to create a text-vector, you should apply that yourself. There are many potential approaches, some simple, some complicated, but no one 'official' or 'best' way.

One easy popular baseline (a fair starting point especially on very small texts like titles) is to average together all the word vectors. That can be as simple as (assuming `numpy` is imported as `np`):

```
np.mean([word_model[word] for word in word_list], axis=0)
```

But, recent versions of Gensim also have a convenience `.get_mean_vector()` method for averaging together sets of vectors (specified as their word-keys, or raw vectors), with some other options:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.get_mean_vector

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to text classification. I need more clarification from you.

(1) What do you mean by `X` as a word or as a text?

(2) What are  "list-of-words" and  "per-word-vectors"?

(3) WHat do you mean by "averaging together all the word vectors."? Do you mean averaging the values of the same words?

Comment: If you're using Python,`X` would be a word if `X = 'apple'`. It'd be a text – in this context, a list-of-words – if `X = ['I', 'ate', 'an', 'apple']`. A list of words is just a Python list, where each item is a word (a string token). 'per-word-vectors' means vectors that exist 1 per word, as after a model-training process (or loading some pretrained vectors). When you have more than one vector – such as 4 different vectors for each word of the text `['I', 'ate', 'an', 'apple']` – you can average them together mathematically (as shown in the invocation of `numpy`'s `mean()` function).